# Как добавить модальное окно к элементам Li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача заключается в том, что бы при нажатии на список `li` появлялась небольшое модальное окно под элементом на который нажали. И там уже его редактировать или удалить. Я попробовал сделать так при клике на `li` (`position: relative`) добавил модалку в li (`position: absolute`) и открыл ее, но прикол в том, что эта модалка находиться под всем списком, и `z-index: 9999` не работает.

Подскажите что делаю не так? или может вы знаете другой способ сделать такое? 
Всем спасибо.

```js
var list = $('#ul li');

list.click((e) => {

  var target = e.target,
    li = $(this).find('li'),
    block = $(target).find('.block');

  if (this != li) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.block').remove();
    $(target)
      .after('<div class="block">4</div>');
    $('.block').css({
      display: 'block'
    });
  } else if (target == $('.block')) {
    console.log('поидее блок')
  }
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 7;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
  <li>lorem__1</li>
  <li>lorem__2</li>
  <li>lorem__3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста код из jsfiddle в вопрос, ибо у меня он например недоступен)

Comment: добавил.....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var list = $('#ul li');

list.on('click', function(e) {
  var offset = $(e.target).offset();
  offset.top = offset.top + $(e.target).height();
  $('.list__wrapper .block').remove();
  $('.list__wrapper').append('<div class="block">4</div>');
  $('.list__wrapper .block').css(offset).show();
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 7;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list__wrapper">
  <ul id="ul">
    <li>lorem__1</li>
    <li>lorem__2</li>
    <li>lorem__3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```